# Why multi-threading is often combined with multiprocessing?

Tags: multithreading, apache, multiprocessing

As a school project, I have to implement a http server so I was looking at existing http server architectures and I came upon the worker Multi-Processing Module.

This module implement a hybrid multi-threaded multi-process server that is, it forks and each forked process spawn his own thread-pool that handle the requests.

That let me wondering, what are the advantages of hybrid multi-process multi-threaded programs over multi-threaded only programs ? Why not keep a single process and spawn a bigger thread-pool ?

Answer (score 3):

Availability.

Your program has nascent flaws, so it is better to let one instance crash with M threads than have it crash with N*M threads.   The (N-1)*M other threads may be able to continue operating, and you may have reduced the likelihood of any of them crashing.

This is also deployed as a technique to deal with resource leakage : after handling N transactions, the server “exec’s” itself, which causes a cleanup of its resources.   I’m pretty sure Thompson&Ritchie didn’t foresee that as a use-case for exec....